# how to pass query parameter to sql file using bigquery operator

Tags: airflow, google-cloud-composer

I need access the parameter passed by BigqueryOperator in sql file, but I am getting error `ERROR - queryParameters argument must have a type <class 'dict'> not <class 'list'>`
I am using below code:

```
t2 = bigquery_operator.BigQueryOperator(
task_id='bq_from_source_to_clean',
sql='prepare.sql',
use_legacy_sql=False,
allow_large_results=True,
query_params=[{ 'name': 'threshold_date', 'parameterType': { 'type': 'STRING' },'parameterValue': { 'value': '2020-01-01' } }],
destination_dataset_table="{}.{}.{}".format('xxxx',
                                            'xxxx',
                                            'temp_airflow_test'),
create_disposition="CREATE_IF_NEEDED",
write_disposition="WRITE_TRUNCATE",
dag=dag
```

)

Sql :

```
select  cast(DATE_ADD(a.dt_2, interval 7 day) as DATE) as dt_1
,a.dt_2
,cast('2010-01-01' as DATE) as dt_3 
from (select cast(@threshold_date as date) as dt_2) a
```

I am using Google composer version **composer-1.7.0-airflow-1.10.2**

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After diving into the source code, it appears that `BigQueryHook` had a bug fixed in Airflow 1.10.3.

The way you defined `query_params` is correct for newer versions of Airflow, and should be a **list** according to BigQuery API : see https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/parameterized-queries#bigquery_query_params_named-python.

Anyway, you are getting this error because in Airflow 1.10.2, `query_params` is defined as a `dict`, see :

https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/1.10.2/airflow/contrib/hooks/bigquery_hook.py#L678

```py
query_param_list = [
    ...
    (query_params, 'queryParameters', None, dict),
    ...
]
```

This causes the internal `_validate_value` function to throw a `TypeError` :

https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/1.10.2/airflow/contrib/hooks/bigquery_hook.py#L1954

```py
def _validate_value(key, value, expected_type):
    """ function to check expected type and raise
    error if type is not correct """
    if not isinstance(value, expected_type):
        raise TypeError("{} argument must have a type {} not {}".format(
            key, expected_type, type(value)))
```

I did not find any example of `query_params` in Airflow 1.10.2 (or any unit tests...), but I think it's just because it is not usable.

These bugs has been fixed by these commits :

- https://github.com/apache/airflow/commit/0c797a830e3370bd6e39f5fcfc128a8fd776912e#diff-ee06f8fcbc476ea65446a30160c2a2b2R784 : change `dict` to `list`
- https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/4876 : update documentation

These changes have been embedded in Airflow 1.10.3, but, as of now, Airflow 1.10.3 is not available in Composer (https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/concepts/versioning/composer-versions#new_environments) : latest version have been released May 16, 2019 and embed version 1.10.2.

Waiting for this new version, I see 2 ways to fix your problem :

- copy/paste fixed versions of `BigQueryOperator` and `BigQueryHook` and embed them in your sources to use them, or extend the existing `BigQueryHook` and override bugged methods. I'm not sure you can patch `BigQueryHook` directly (no access to those files in Composer environment)
- templatize your SQL query yourself (and not use `query_params`)

Answer (score 2):

Sharing two ways to pass query params in BigQuery operator -

1. **Jinja Templating** - In the below query you see *'{{ (execution_date - macros.timedelta(hours=1)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00') }}'* is the jina tempate which will get resolved at runtime.

   SELECT owner_display_name, title, view_count FROM `bigquery-public-data.stackoverflow.posts_questions` WHERE creation_date > CAST('*{{ (execution_date - macros.timedelta(hours=1)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00') }}*' AS TIMESTAMP) ORDER BY view_count DESC LIMIT 100
2. **query_params** - for in clause, type would be array and in array type type should be type of the column in big query.

   query_params=[ { 'name': 'DATE_IN_CLAUSE', 'parameterType': { 'type': 'ARRAY','arrayType': { 'type' :'TIMESTAMP'} },'parameterValue': { 'arrayValues': [{ 'value': datetime.utcnow().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00') }, { 'value': (datetime.utcnow() - timedelta(hours=1)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00') }] } },
   { 'name': 'COUNT', 'parameterType': { 'type': 'INTEGER' },'parameterValue': { 'value': 1 } } ]

   SELECT owner_display_name, title, view_count FROM bigquery-public-data.stackoverflow.posts_questions WHERE creation_date in UNNEST(@DATE_IN_CLAUSE) and view_count > @COUNT ORDER BY view_count DESC LIMIT 100

Note - Upper query and params may not give you results but they will succeed without any error. These examples are just for demonstration of how to pass params.

Answer (score 1):

This is definitely a bug with composer (Airflow 1.10.2) we fixed it by pulling down the airflow files from github and patching the bigquery_hook.py file and then referencing the fixed file in bigquery_operator.py (both uploaded to a lib folder), the fixes are:

1. bigquery_operator.py (line 21)

   from lib.bigquery_hook import BigQueryHook
2. bigquery_hook.py

   (line 678) (query_params, 'queryParameters', None, list),

   (line 731) if 'useLegacySql' in configuration['query'] and configuration['query']['useLegacySql'] and \

then in your dag, reference the uploaded BQ operator: "from lib.bigquery_operator import BigQueryOperator"